# Use PHP to sort files into directories

Tags: php, sorting, directory

I want to sort my `.txt` files after upload in orders, first year, then month, then day.

My text has the format: `YYYY-MM-DD-40-numbers and letters.txt`
(e.g.: `2014-01-12-a23ert78df23456ewr91234df789dfh456hj912er.txt`

And here's the directory structure I want:

- 2014

  - 01

    - 01
    - 02
    - 03
    - ...
  - 02
  - 03
  - ...

If the directory doesn't exist, the script should create one.

Now I want to put this into my old PHP script:

```
<?php
$uploaddir = './';
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Datei erfolgreich erhalten: $file";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you going:

```
// Assuming $file is 2014-01-12-a23ert78df23456ewr91234df789dfh456hj912er.txt
$date = substr($file, 0, 10); // 2014-01-02
$path = str_replace("-","/",$date); // 2014/01/02
if(!is_dir($uploaddir . "/" . $path)) {
    mkdir($uploaddir . "/" . $path, 0777, true); // Third param 'true' makes this recursive
}

// Now the folder exists, you can move your file
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . "/" . $path . "/" . $file;
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Datei erfolgreich erhalten: $file";
}
```

You'll want to add to this, for error checking (make sure you were successful in creating the directory), etc. But this is the approach you are looking for.

Comment: @user3188041 Glad to help. I only recently discovered that `mkdir` had that option to be recursive, sure it easier not having to create each directory one at a time.